# How to systematically classify Mathematica expressions?

Tags: pattern-matching

How to systematically classify Mathematica expressions?  I can think of using `Head[]`, `Depth[]`, `Length[]`, and some special pattern based on the problems at hand.  What other key words, or functions should I consider?

### Update

I mostly want to group symbols by how nested its list are, and what kinds of elements the lists have.  For example

```
{_String, _Symbol}

{{_Integer}, _String}

_String
```

would be considered *three* distinct types.

Comment: This one seems too broad ... to classify for what?

Comment: For example: Is this useul to you? `Tally[Length /@ Characters@Names[]]`

Comment: It sounds as though the questioner wants to define the set of features which can be used to uniquely resolve Mathematica expressions into a set of classes. A definition of the set of classes would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your updated example, you would find the "classification" using your scheme by replacing the lowest level elements with a pattern based on their heads:

```
classify[expression_] := Map[Blank[Head[#]] &, expression, {-1}]
```

Then you can apply this on template examples of the patterns you listed:

```
a = {"string", symbol};
b = {{42}, "string"};
c= "string";

classify[a]
classify[b]
classify[c]
(* {_String, _Symbol} *)
(* {{_Integer}, _String} *)
(* _String *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you considered looking at [the book from S. Wolfram](http://www.wolframscience.com/nksonline/toc.html) a new kind of science. There he discuses some main **principals and rules** applied to mathematica in particular Chapter 11: The Notion of Computation and further chapters.

Comment: Could you summarize that chapter for those who haven't read it yet?

Comment: I would claim that you cannot learn *anything* about *Mathematica* expressions from that book. I own the hard copy because my kids like the patterns.

Answer (score -1):

The function `Depth` will separate the examples of the expressions you give  into three distinct classes.

```
exps = {{_String, _Symbol}, {{_Integer}, _String}, _String}
Depth /@ exps
```

> {3, 4, 2}

Comment: Well, `Depth` only gives the maximum depth, so it's not indicative of the structure of the expression. For instance, `Depth@{{_Integer}, {_String}}` is also 4, but it's different from the second example above. For deeper depths, there will be several possible combinations of nestings that will give the same value

Comment: Yes absolutely true, in as much as it correctly classifies the three examples given it accurately separates the example data. Adding the set of contained heads, or a positionally ordered list of heads , would lead to a more refined classification. Or adding something like  Belisarius suggests, a hash based on name length would also be an improvement. But to know which would suit best would probably require a more refined question.